# Converting decimal array to hexa

Tags: c

I am trying to run a sample code to convert an array of decimal number to hexa and store them in another array. The code works if I scanf the numbers but when using the array I am getting segmentation error.

```
#include <stdio.h> 

int main(void)
{   
    int  bin = 0;
   // int num ;
    int i = 0, rem;
    char hex_arr[60];

    //printf("Enter a decimal number: "); 
    //scanf("%d", &num); 
    int num [60] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 127, 128, 31, 239, 31, 254, 1, 255, 240, 0, 0, 0, 0, 127, 255, 192, 255, 255, 255, 128, 127, 231, 192, 120, 14, 0, 120, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};

    for (int k = 0; k <= 59; i++)
    {
        rem = num[k] % 16;  // get the right most digit

        if (rem < 10)
        {
            hex_arr[i++] = 48 + rem;
        }
        else
        {
            hex_arr[i++] = 55 + rem;
        }

        num[k] /= 16;  // get the quotient
    }
    printf("0x");

    for(int j = i - 1; j >= 0 ; j--)  // print the hex_arr in reverse order
    {
        printf("%c", hex_arr[j]);
    }    

    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Is the `i++` in `for (int k = 0; k <= 59; i++)` intentional? Or did you mean `k++`?

Comment: Also, I don't understand what is the use of this line `num[k] /= 16`.

Comment: Do you want to convert all integers of `num` to their respective hexadecimal and store them in `hex_arr`?

Comment: Show some examples of input and expected output.

Comment: I very much doubt that this "works when using scanf".

Comment: The reason it "works when using `scanf`" is that the scanf version of your code was reading a *single* integer.  Converting a single integer to hexadecimal is a straightforward problem.  It's not clear what you're trying to do with that array of input integers.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get rid of all "magic numbers".

- `k <= 59`-> `k < 60`
- `48 + rem` -> `'0' + rem`
- `55 + rem` -> `'7' + rem`.

Wait, how does `'7'` make any sense? Turns out it doesn't & the use of "magic numbers" were hiding that bug. You probably meant 65, which should be written as `'A'`.

(Strictly speaking, arithmetic using symbol values isn't well-defined in C, since only the symbols `'0'` to `'9'` are actually guaranteed to be a contiguous sequence. In practice "it will work" on all mainstream systems.)

As noted in comments, `for (int k=0; ...; i++)` probably doesn't make any sense either.

Comment: I don't think that using the number `55` was a "bug". In OP's code, when that line of code is executed, the variable `rem` has a value between `10` and `15`, so the expression `55 + rem` evaluates to an ASCII code between `65` and `70`, i.e. between `'A'` and `'F'`. Therefore, that part of OP's code seems to work as intended.

Comment: Though `'A' + (rem - 10)` would be clearer.

Comment: Oh well....  C uses karma extensively: write really weird code, get really weird results. At this point maybe just toss this whole snippet in the garbage and google "integer to hex string conversion c". Sensible solutions are likely contain a look-up table `"01234567890ABCDEF"`.

Comment: The i++ was  mistake I didn't notice changing to K++ everything works as it should.

Comment: @AmgA: In future, you may want to run your code line by line in a [debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/12149471) while monitoring the values of all variables, in order to determine at which point your program stops behaving as intended. That way, it should be easy for you to find such bugs yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Would this help

Notes

1. num is now defined as a unsigned char array - you can cast in ByteToASCII  if this is a problem
2. It converts the whole string in one go but it's easy to convert to handle one byte at a time
3. it was unclear if you want the num array as a list of nybbles or as a whole byte but, again, that would be easy to change in this code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<ctype.h>

#include <stdio.h> 

void ByteToASCII (char * string, unsigned char   byte )
      {
         char    curval      ;

         curval = (char) ('0'  | (byte >> 4)) ;

         if ('9' < curval)
         {
            curval += (char) ('A' - '9' - 1) ;
         }

         *string++ = curval ;

         byte <<= 4 ;

         curval = (char) ('0'  | (byte >> 4)) ;

         if ('9' < curval)
         {
            curval += (char) ('A' - '9' - 1) ;
         }

         *string++ = curval ;
         *string = 0 ; // keep null terminated
      }

int main(void)
{   
    //printf("Enter a decimal number: "); 
    //scanf("%d", &num); 
    
    unsigned char num [60] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 127, 128, 31, 239, 31, 254, 1, 255, 240, 0, 0, 0, 0, 127, 255, 192, 255, 255, 255, 128, 127, 231, 192, 120, 14, 0, 120, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    char hex_arr[(2 * sizeof(num)) + 1];

    for (int k = 0; k < sizeof(num); k++)
    {
        ByteToASCII (&hex_arr[k * 2], num[k]) ;
    }
    printf(hex_arr);
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: No, need an extra byte for the null terminator in hex_array

Comment: @jabberwocky - correct, left off the 2 * (doh!)

Comment: @jabberwocky - it's done in the conversion function (always appended to the string as it goes along)